# XAML For Reflection Effect

Tags: wpf, text, effects

I'm a XAML/WPF newbie, and I thought I'd write an alarm clock application to get into it.  I want to get past the basic textboxes, dropdowns etc, which are fairly simple once you get the hang of the layout model, but I'd like to get into the graphics side of things.

I'd like to display alarm clock digits on a black backdrop, but importantly the alarm clock numbers to have that reflection effect like they're stood up on a piece of glass (like how Apple marketing often is implemented).

How do I get started with this?  I'm looking at Charles Petzold's stuff for inspiration but struggling a little.

Comment: I posted a reflection control on my blog at http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2007/11/21/WPF-Reflection-Control.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [XAML Reflections](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/wpfsamples/entry3741.aspx) sample on the [WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/).

If you need more samples, the WindowsClient site also has a [Control Gallery](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/default.aspx) with list of useful snippets, tool sna dsytle and there's also the full list of [WPF Samples](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/wpfsamples/default.aspx) you can download and study.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think that this might be easily adapted enough from an image to text:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFImageEffects.aspx